# Drop event not fired when dropping on border of a table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery UI draggable plugin to drag divs into a table.

My problem is that sometimes when dragging into a table cell I experience that the drop event is not triggered. It seems to happen when dropped exactly on the one pixel that separates two cells (vertical or horizontal). I've tried to set the border to 0 but still I have the problem.

Check out this [**simplified example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Claudius/FqWNr/2/).

Comment: What is the desired outcome...because I think you can only drop when the droppable lights up(highlights)

Comment: @Tejasva Dhyani I want to make it impossible, when dropping over the table, to "lose" the draggable div - hope it makes sense

Comment: If anyone is interested, here is the real case - needless to mention still in beta: [http://wsolver.apphb.com/](http://wsolver.apphb.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a comment by Tejasva Dhyani and chat with Tats_innit I found the answer:

jQuery gets confused (and rightfully so) when dropping while the draggable div is just between two droppable elements (cells).

Ie if dropping while 15px is over one cell and 15px is over another the drop event is not triggered.

All I did was to set the width and height to an uneven number, [see jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Claudius/FqWNr/4/):

Answer (score 2):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/YNUzx/1/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/YNUzx/2/

`Tolerance` option should be set to `touch` for better drag functionality :)

**or** use `pointer` as tolerance: mouse pointer overlaps the droppable

Good read: http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#option-tolerance

**Behaviour**: Now when you will drag say "1" to the table cell a touch will trigger the drop in the table, rest you can see that in demo.

Hope this helps,

Following line does the trick: `tolerance: "touch",`

**code**

```
$(".dragbox").draggable({
    revert: true
});

$("table tr td").droppable({
    accept: ".dragbox",
    tolerance: "touch",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).css({
            'background-color': 'white'
        }).html(ui.draggable.find('span').text());
    },
    over: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).css({
            'background-color': '#DCFFDB'
        });
    },
    out: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).css({
            'background-color': 'white'
        });
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

What I suggest is use the 'touch' tolerance option but remove the margin of the draggables, since they are creating problem for the proper functionality. Instead use a wrapper div for the draggables and give that div some margin. This might help http://jsfiddle.net/YNUzx/3/

Also I would recommend that you increase the width and height of td to see the proper working.

EDIT:
try this http://jsfiddle.net/YNUzx/4/ I think I got the solution

Comment: Thanks, but your jsfiddle example drops om many cells, your edited link have the original problem. Using your first link I might be able to determine which cell is closest to the pointer, and then only highlight that one and when dropping only drop there. But my real table is 15x15 and it might slow things down...

Comment: Actually tolerance by default is 'intersect' that means atleast 50% intersection. so what you can do is remove the border of the td and put a dummy table(with a lower z-index) and put exactly where your table resides. this way there will be a td (always) in which droppable exists more than 50% ... also, great work with the board game